# HAL define bug with STM32WLE5CCU microcontroller

Tags: c, stm32, init, hal, stm32cubeide

Im trying to use interrupts from UART DMA and SubGhz with STM32WLE5CCU in STM32Cube IDE.
I noticed that I don’t get interrupts from both when I don’t define delay time between the configurations. The current code:

```
MX_GPIO_Init();
HAL_Delay(25); // because of bug
MX_SUBGHZ_Init();
MX_DMA_Init();
HAL_Delay(25); // because of bug
MX_USART2_UART_Init();
….
```

without that HAL_Delay command I won’t get interrupts from UART and SubGhz?
I already tried to reduce the delay time to 10ms and it doesn’t work.

I tried to use interrupt without the delay commands and it doesn’t work. Looks like the minimum delay time is ~20ms.

does anyone familiar with this bug and knows how to solve it?
THANKS!

Comment: Try different initialization sequences until you find out which particular operations need time in between, and that may suggest what event you need to watch for (instead of a fixed time delay).

Comment: Sounds as if some of these functions do not properly wait for flags from the hardware indicating that it is finished.

Comment: as @BenVoigt mentioned; it is a bug in stm32cubeide and I have encountered this type of problem before for example https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/605937/294234